# Bases and Matroids of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matroids

I would appreciate some guidance regarding the concept of matroids in a graph.
I have the following graph: V = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} with E = {(1,2),(1,3,(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(5,6),(5,7),(6,7)}.
The first question is giving the number of elements of the basis of the graph.
The way I understood the basis of a matroid is the maximum independent set of F, and in the graph above we can only have a maximum independent set of only 2 Edges. Does this imply that the number of elements of the basis of the graph is 2?

Further, I have to state the number of different basis the graph can have. This question I am really not sure how to go about.

Appreciate all guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please answer the following: how are the independent sets in a graphic matroid defined? The answer to this question should help you understand the problem better.